# creating a table if not exist; otherwise repopulate it

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

In a python script a table is dropped and recreated but I noticed it errors if the table does not exists in the first place.

```
shp2pgsql = r"shp2pgsql -s 4135 -d "+path+" asmithe.bigtable "
psql = 'psql -U asmithe -h example.org -d xyz -c "ANALYZE asmithe.bigtable"' 
subprocess.Popen(shp2pgsql +" | "+psql, shell=True).wait()
```

gives

```
ERROR:  relation "asmithe.bigtable" does not exist
```

How can it be safeguarded so that if the table doesn't exist it just creates it?

Comment: Wrap it in a `DO` block that checks `information_schema.tables` to see if it exists and only executes the `CREATE TABLE` if it doesn't.

Comment: The psql command does not even read the pipe: `-c, --command=COMMAND    run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit`

Comment: @CraigRinger what's a `DO` block?

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` flag directs psql to *only* use the string after -c as a command.
To demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/sh

    # This one fails; the pipe is never read
echo 'create TABLE omg (wtf integer NOT NULL);' \
     | psql -U postgres -d postgres -c 'ANALYZE public.omg;'

    # this one works; *only* the pipe (stdin) is read and executed
echo 'CREATE TABLE omg (wtf integer NOT NULL); ANALYZE public.omg; DROP TABLE public.omg;' \
     | psql -U postgres -d postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer, the `-c` option causes psql to not read the pipe. 
Why do you execute ANALYZE? in this place is wrong. Simply remove it:

```
shp2pgsql = r"shp2pgsql -s 4135 -d "+path+" asmithe.bigtable "
psql = 'psql -U asmithe -h example.org -d xyz' 
subprocess.Popen(shp2pgsql +" | "+psql, shell=True).wait()
```